# Different height for the <li>

Tags: html, css

Goal:
Make the text "bbb" to have the same font height as "aaa" but the height of the li.ttt should have the same height as the font-size: xx-large;

Problem:
Don't know how to do it. I tried using "height" but it doesn't work.

https://jsfiddle.net/qc89dwz7/

```css
LI.filtered A {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1px 20px 1px 4px;
  background: #F0F0FF url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/luchesa-vol-9/128/Lollipop-16.png) no-repeat scroll right 0;
  background-position: right bottom;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #08C;
  text-decoration: none;
}
LI.filtered .testt {
  background: #F0F0FF;
  padding: 1px 4px 1px 4px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #08C;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#result-filters {
  margin: 0, 0, -30px;
}
#result-filters UL {
  display: inline;
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}
LI.filtered,
#result-filters LI.filtered {
  padding-left: 0;
  background: transparent none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
#result-filters UL LI {
  margin: 0 8px 0 0;
  float: left;
}
LI.ttt A {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1px 4px 1px 20px;
  background: #F0F0FF url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/luchesa-vol-9/128/Lollipop-16.png) no-repeat scroll left 0;
  background-position: left;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #08C;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: xx-large;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
  min-height: 61px;
  border: 0;
  line-height: 1.2;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  width: 137px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Tahoma;
}
```

```html
<div id="result-filters">
  <ul>

    <li class="filtered">
      <a href="">
  aaa
  </a>
    </li>
    <li class="ttt">
      <a href="">bbb</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `font-size` ?

Comment: Add fiddle make your question nice

Comment: The `height` is not working because the background is set for A not li. Add a background-color along with height, You will know what I mean. http://jsfiddle.net/Ltk1r5Lv/

Comment: `xx-large` is only a valid value for `font-size`. For `height`, you need to specify it in `px`, `em`, or `%`.

Answer (score 0):

`xx-large` translates to `32px`

Knowing this, you can establish the height and line-height of the two list-items separately:

```
li.filtered {
    height: 12px;
    line-height: 12px;
    }

li.ttt {
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
    }
```

You can then establish the font-size of *aaa* and *bbb* as `12px`:

```
li.filtered a,
li.ttt a {
    font-size: 12px;
    }
```

**Putting it all together:**

```css
LI.filtered A {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1px 20px 1px 4px;
  background: #F0F0FF url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/luchesa-vol-9/128/Lollipop-16.png) no-repeat scroll right 0;
  background-position: right bottom;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #08C;
  text-decoration: none;
}
LI.filtered .testt {
  background: #F0F0FF;
  padding: 1px 4px 1px 4px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #08C;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#result-filters {
  margin: 0, 0, -30px;
}
#result-filters UL {
  display: inline;
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}
LI.filtered,
#result-filters LI.filtered {
  padding-left: 0;
  background: transparent none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
#result-filters UL LI {
  margin: 0 8px 0 0;
  float: left;
}
LI.ttt A {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1px 4px 1px 20px;
  background: #F0F0FF url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/luchesa-vol-9/128/Lollipop-16.png) no-repeat scroll left 0;
  background-position: left;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #08C;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: xx-large;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
  min-height: 61px;
  border: 0;
  line-height: 1.2;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  width: 137px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Tahoma;
}

li.filtered,
li.ttt {
    display:block;
    background-color: rgba(244,244,244,1);
    }

li.filtered {
    height: 12px;
    line-height: 12px;
    margin: 10px;
    }

#result-filters li.filtered {
    margin-top: 10px;
    }
        
li.ttt {
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
    }

li.filtered a,
li.ttt a {
    font-size: 12px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="result-filters">
  <ul>

    <li class="filtered">
      <a href="">
  aaa
  </a>
    </li>
    <li class="ttt">
      <a href="">bbb</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

## =====

**A Simpler Alternative for Plain Colour Backgrounds**

If you wish to *middle-align* the two same-font-size list-items *over a plain colour background*, simply colour in the background of `li.ttt` and leave the background of `li.filtered` transparent:

```
li.filtered,
li.ttt {
    display:block;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
    }

li.ttt {
    background-color: rgba(244,244,244,1);
    }

li.filtered a,
li.ttt a {
    font-size: 12px;
    }
```

**Putting it all together (simpler version):**

```css
LI.filtered A {
      position: relative;
      padding: 1px 20px 1px 4px;
      background: #F0F0FF url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/luchesa-vol-9/128/Lollipop-16.png) no-repeat scroll right 0;
      background-position: right bottom;
      font-weight: 400;
      color: #08C;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    LI.filtered .testt {
      background: #F0F0FF;
      padding: 1px 4px 1px 4px;
      font-weight: 400;
      color: #08C;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    #result-filters {
      margin: 0, 0, -30px;
    }
    #result-filters UL {
      display: inline;
      list-style: outside none none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-size: 12px;
      font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    LI.filtered,
    #result-filters LI.filtered {
      padding-left: 0;
      background: transparent none repeat scroll 0 0;
    }
    #result-filters UL LI {
      margin: 0 8px 0 0;
      float: left;
    }
    LI.ttt A {
      position: relative;
      padding: 1px 4px 1px 20px;
      background: #F0F0FF url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/luchesa-vol-9/128/Lollipop-16.png) no-repeat scroll left 0;
      background-position: left;
      font-weight: 400;
      color: #08C;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: xx-large;
      -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
      -moz-border-radius: 4px;
      border-radius: 4px;
      background-color: #F4F4F4;
      min-height: 61px;
      border: 0;
      line-height: 1.2;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
      width: 137px;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: Tahoma;
    }


li.filtered,
li.ttt {
    display:block;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
    }

li.ttt {
    background-color: rgba(244,244,244,1);
    }

li.filtered a,
li.ttt a {
    font-size: 12px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="result-filters">
  <ul>

    <li class="filtered">
      <a href="">
        aaa
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="ttt">
      <a href="">bbb</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Is it possible to make the object of "aaa" and "bbb" to be in a straight line in a across, if you understand what I mean?

Comment: Yes, you can straightforwardly do this with the setup above, by adding `#result-filters li.filtered {margin-top: 10px;}` (see my edit above)... BUT, if you simply want to achieve this alignment over a plain colour background, then (a much easier solution) you can set the *same styles* for all list-items (height, line-height etc.) and simply color in the background of `li.ttt` (as @Manoj Kumar mentioned above).

Comment: For more detail, see my post above for the simpler solution, which I've now added.