# Make the text "bbb" to be beside to the icon, not flatten together

Tags: html, css

Goal:
Make the letter "bbb" to be visible and the text should be beside to the icon

Problem:
I tried to move the text to the right side but it doesn't work. Do you guys know how to do it?

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5f7qjLgf/1/)

Thanks!

```css
#result-filters {
    margin: 20px, 20px, 30px;
}
#result-filters UL {
    display: inline;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#result-filters UL LI {
    margin: 0 8px 0 0;
    float: left;
}


LI.filtered A {
    position: relative;
    padding: 1px 20px 1px 4px;
    background: #F0F0FF url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/luchesa-vol-9/128/Lollipop-16.png) no-repeat scroll right 0;
    background-position: right bottom;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #08C;
    text-decoration: none;
}

LI.filtered, #result-filters LI.filtered {
    padding-left: 0;
    background: transparent none repeat scroll 0 0;
}

li.ttt a
{
    position: relative;
    padding: 1px 40px 1px 4px;
    background: #F0F0FF url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/luchesa-vol-9/128/Lollipop-16.png) no-repeat scroll left 0;
    background-position: left;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #08C;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #F4F4F4;       
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div id="result-filters">
    <ul>
        <li class="filtered"><a href="">
  aaa
  </a>

        </li>
        <li class="ttt"><a href="">     bbb</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Practically the same question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33544919/different-height-for-the-li

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just increase the left padding. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5f7qjLgf/2/

```
li.ttt a
{
    padding: 1px 40px 1px 20px;
    .....
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys for your help!

Comment: @HelloWorld no problem! Happy to help!

Answer (score 2):

There are a lots of way that you can solve your problem. As, @AtheistP3ace changed the padding of a element to prevent the text from covering the image. I use `:before Pseudo-element`([CSS ::before Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp)). You can check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/5f7qjLgf/4/).