# Move objects' position without affecting the background

Tags: html, css

Goal:
Move the object of the icon and the text "bbb" to right side, about 10 pixel. The background should be remained in the same position.

Problem:
I tried to do it but I failed. Sorry!

Thanks!

```css
#result-filters {
    margin: 20px, 20px, 30px;
}
#result-filters UL {
    display: inline;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#result-filters UL LI {
    margin: 0 8px 0 0;
    float: left;
}


LI.filtered A {
    position: relative;
    padding: 1px 20px 1px 4px;
    background: #F0F0FF url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/luchesa-vol-9/128/Lollipop-16.png) no-repeat scroll right 0;
    background-position: right bottom;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #08C;
    text-decoration: none;
}

LI.filtered, #result-filters LI.filtered {
    padding-left: 0;
    background: transparent none repeat scroll 0 0;
}

li.ttt a
{
    position: relative;
    padding: 1px 40px 1px 20px;
    background: #F0F0FF url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/luchesa-vol-9/128/Lollipop-16.png) no-repeat scroll left 0;
    background-position: left;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #08C;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #F4F4F4;       
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div id="result-filters">
    <ul>
        <li class="filtered"><a href="">
  aaa
  </a>

        </li>
        <li class="ttt"><a href="">bbb</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

> https://jsfiddle.net/5f7qjLgf/7/

[image]

Comment: You want aaa and bbb to look similar? With text on left and icon on right?

Comment: do you mean this: https://jsfiddle.net/5f7qjLgf/8/  ?? edited: I've just made it as an answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make the text "bbb" to be beside to the icon, not flatten together](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33547457/make-the-text-bbb-to-be-beside-to-the-icon-not-flatten-together)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change this css:

```
li.ttt a {
    padding: 1px 30px 1px 30px;    
    background-position: 10px ;
}
```

so, 10px less to the right of the `a` tag, 10px more to the left (moving the "bbb" and `background-position:10px`so you move the icon 10pc to the right.

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5f7qjLgf/9/)**

Comment: Thank you for your help!